# How do I select just mutual rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a source_id and destination_id and a message and I want to group messages together.  There can only be one message between a given source_id and destination_id, but I only want rows that have a mutual response for a given ID (say id 1).  In the following examples, I want rows #1, #2, #4 and #5 because there is a mutual response between id 1 and 2 and between id 1 and id 4 (id 1 sent a message to id 2 and id 2 sent a message to id 1, similarly, id 1 sent a message to id 4 and id 4 sent a message to id 1).  I don't want id 3 because it has no mutual response.

How do I select this in SQL?  (I'm using PostgreSQL btw)

```
Example:
table messages
#  source_id destination_id message
1  1          2             hello
2  2          1             hi
3  1          3             bye
4  1          4             thanks
5  4          1             okay
6  3          5             blablabla
7  5          3             hooray
```

Preferably, I want my select to return these 4 rows:

```
1  1          2             hello
2  2          1             hi
3  1          4             thanks
4  4          1             okay
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you want 6 and 7?

Comment: Because I would only want mutual conversations for user ID 1.  Rows 6 and 7 are mutual conversations from other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing `exists`:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where exists (select 1
              from messages m2
              where m2.source_id = m.destination_id and
                    m2.source_id = m.destination_id
             );
```

In your example, this would also return rows 6 and 7, because those seem to follow the rule you specified.

If you want `1` to be one of the ids, then include a filter for that:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where 1 in (m.source_id, m.destination_id) and
      exists (select 1
              from messages m2
              where m2.source_id = m.destination_id and
                    m2.source_id = m.destination_id
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join:

```
select m1.*
from messages m1
join messages m2
  on  m1.source_id = m2.destination_id 
  and m2.source_id = m1.destination_id 
where 1 in (m1.source_id, m2.source_id)
```